# Change-of-coordinate matrix and involutory matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification

I am trying to learn linear algebra, but am currently having trouble wrapping my head around the intuition of how a change of coordinate matrix can be involutory

Let

$$
A = \left\{\begin{bmatrix}
        1 \\ 
        0 
    \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
        1 \\ 
        1 
    \end{bmatrix}
    \right\} \text{ and } B = \left\{\begin{bmatrix}
        1 \\ 
        1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
        1 \\ 
        0  
    \end{bmatrix} \right\}.
$$

be two ordered bases in $R^2$. To determine $P_{A\to B}$ I augment A on B s.t.

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 1 & \bigm | & 1 & 1\\
        1 & 0 & \bigm | & 0 & 1\\
    \end{pmatrix}\xrightarrow{\substack{r_2-r_1 \\ -1r_2 \\ r_1-r_2}}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & \bigm | & 0 & 1\\
        0 & 1 & \bigm | & 1 & 0\\
    \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Thus
$$
P_{A\to B} = \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 1 \\ 
        1 & 0 
    \end{pmatrix}.
$$
And similarily for $P_{B\to A}$
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1 & \bigm | & 1 & 1\\
    0 & 1 & \bigm | & 1 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}\xrightarrow{\substack{r_1-r_2}}
\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & \bigm | & 0 & 1\\
    0 & 1 & \bigm | & 1 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
And $P_{B\to A}$ is also determined to be
$$
P_{B\to A} = \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1 \\ 
    1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Now, obviously $P_{A\to B}$ and $P_{B\to A}$ are inverses of eachother as $$(P_{A\to B})\times (P_{B\to A}) = (P_{B\to A})\times (P_{A\to B}) = I.$$ However, intuitively I have trouble understanding how the inverse, that is the way back from basis B to A is the same as the way from A to B? Is it simply because the bases A and B have got the same set of vectors as elements.

Alas, I am not sure if my question even makes sense; however, I hope you can help shed some light on my question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To change from $A$ to $B$, you basically swap the two basis vectors.
Since swapping is clearly a symmetric operation, the two change-of-coordinates matrices are the same.

In fact, the matrix $P_{A\to B}$ (or $P_{B\to A}$) can be obtained by swapping the two columns of the identity matrix.